# Add only available date values to monthly dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with employee time sheets, total hour worked as well as overtime hours.

```
example = pd.DataFrame({'Employee': ["Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Bob", "Peter", "Peter"], 'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'],
                       'Total Hour': [1.5, 2.2, 7, 1, 3, 6], 'Overtime': [1.5, 0, 1.2, 2.3, 1.7, 5]})
print(example)

  Employee        date  Total Hour  Overtime
0     Alex  2021-01-01         1.5       1.5
1     Alex  2021-01-01         2.2       0.0
2     Alex  2021-01-03         7.0       1.2
3      Bob  2021-01-02         1.0       2.3
4    Peter  2021-01-01         3.0       1.7
5    Peter  2021-01-02         6.0       5.0
```

I want to create a monthly DataFrame with all the days of the month and fill only available timesheets in it, something like this:

```
                          2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03  2021-01-04  2021-01-05  ... 2021-01-31
  Employee           
0     Alex   Total Hour       3.7                     7.0
1     Alex   Overtime         1.5                     1.2
2     Bob    Total Hour                   1 
3     Bob    Overtime                     2.3
4     Peter  Total Hour       3.0         6
5     Peter  Overtime         1.7         5
```

So as employees enter their hours, this will become more complete.

I tried to figure it out but I think I am missing something very fundamental here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) level 0 to convert column MultiIndex to row MultiIndex:

```
result_df = example.pivot_table(
    index='Employee',
    columns='date',
    values=['Total Hour', 'Overtime'],
    aggfunc='sum'
).stack(level=0)
```

Or equivalently with [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to swap column and row MultiIndexes:

```
result_df = example.groupby(['Employee', 'date']).sum().stack().unstack(level=1)
```

`result_df`:

```
date                 2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
Employee                                               
Alex     Overtime           1.5         NaN         1.2
         Total Hour         3.7         NaN         7.0
Bob      Overtime           NaN         2.3         NaN
         Total Hour         NaN         1.0         NaN
Peter    Overtime           1.7         5.0         NaN
         Total Hour         3.0         6.0         NaN
```

Either approach can be followed with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to order level 1 so that Overtime appears first and Total Hour appears second per Employee. Then [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for some clean up of index and column labels:

```
result_df = result_df.reindex(
    ['Overtime', 'Total Hour'], level=1
).rename_axis(
    index=['Employee', 'Hours'], columns=None
).reset_index()
```

`result_df`:

```
  Employee       Hours  2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03
0     Alex    Overtime         1.5         NaN         1.2
1     Alex  Total Hour         3.7         NaN         7.0
2      Bob    Overtime         NaN         2.3         NaN
3      Bob  Total Hour         NaN         1.0         NaN
4    Peter    Overtime         1.7         5.0         NaN
5    Peter  Total Hour         3.0         6.0         NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was very helpful. Is there any way I can  create something like this: ` pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-01-31') ` and then fill it so I always get the full month regardless of which day we are? Another benefit of that would be able to see if there was a day that nobody worked.

Comment: Yes you can `reindex` the columns with the date_range _after_ pivoting/grouping `.reindex(columns=pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-01-31'))` This assumes that the `date` column is `datetime64[ns]` if it's not you can either convert the column to datetime `example['date'] = pd.to_datetime(example['date'])` before pivoting/grouping or convert the date_range to strings `.reindex(columns=pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-01-31').date.astype(str))`